# Envio de e-mail con angularJs y PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, email

Buenas noches, estoy teniendo problemas para realizar el envío de email utilizando angularJs y PHP. Estoy utilizando el servicio http de angular y mail() de PHP. En la sección network me dice que se envió el formulario pero el email nunca llega.
Si alguien sabe una forma de resolver esto seria de gran ayuda, muchas gracias.

Controlador angularJs:

```
    angular.module('pandu').controller('ContactCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', ContactCtrl]);

    function ContactCtrl($scope, $http) {

        $scope.master = {};
        $scope.user = {};

        $scope.submit = function(){
            console.log($scope.user);
            $scope.method = 'POST';
            $scope.url = 'send_email.php';

            $scope.request = $http({
                method : 'POST',
                url : $scope.url,
                data : $.param($scope.user),
                headers : {'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(response) {
                    $scope.codeStatus = response.data;
                    console.log("success",response);
                }).
                error(function(response) {
                    $scope.codeStatus = response || "Request failed";
                    console.log("error",response);
                });

            console.log("$scope.request",$scope.request);
        };
    }
```

send_email.php:

```
<?php
    $errors = array();      
    $response = array();    
    $post_date = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $data = json_decode($post_date);

    $to  = 'mariadiaz20151515@gmail.com';
    $from = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];   
    $asunto = "Mensaje enviado por: $name ".$name;

    var_dump($to);
    var_dump($from);
    var_dump($name);
    var_dump($message);
    var_dump($asunto);

    if (empty($name)) {
        $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.'; 
    }
    if (empty($from)) {
        $errors['email'] = 'E-mail is required.';
    }
    if (empty($message)) {
        $errors['message'] = 'Message is required.';
    }
    if ( !empty($errors)) {
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['errors']  = $errors;
    } 
    else {
        // Para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera Content-type
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        // Cabeceras adicionales
        $headers .= 'To: Email <'.$to.'>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'From: Recordatorio '.$from.'<'.$from.'>' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Cc: '.$from. "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Bcc: '.$from. "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        if(mail($to, $asunto, $message, $headers)) {
            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Thank you for sending e-mail.';
        } else  {
            $response['errors']  = $errors;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Network:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este es el email que estas utilizando para hacer las pruebas? `$to  = 'mariadiaz20151515@gmail.com';`

Comment: si :) . Cree ese email para probar el envio de mensajes.

Comment: En la carpeta de spam / no-deseado, ahi te has fijado?

Comment: Desde que ambiente pruebas? tu pc local? revisaste si la funcion mail() esta habilitada en tu apache?

Comment: si :( lamentablemente no me llegan tampoco en spam. Lo pruebo en hostinger y en 260mb.net con cuentas gratuitas.